# SET statement with sp_msforeachdb

Tags: sql

does anybody know why this script won't work?

EXECUTE sp_msforeachdb 'USE ?
IF DB_NAME() NOT IN(''master'',''msdb'',''tempdb'',''model'',''ReportServer'')
ALTER DATABASE ? SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF'

It executes fine, but does not exclude master and tempdb.

So the result is this:

Option 'AUTO_CLOSE' cannot be set in database 'master'.
Option 'AUTO_CLOSE' cannot be set in database 'tempdb'.

Answer (score 0):

No idea, but sp_msforeachdb is undocumented and famously unreliable.  Use something else instead, eg [A reliable and flexible replacement for sp_MSforeachdb](https://sqlblog.org/2020/08/04/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb).